# How can I test a variable as confounding in linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, lm

I'm currently doing the statistical analysis I'm going to use in my article. It's about sleep and some functioning/cognitive measures on mood disorder patients.

The problem I have is: I correlated a functioning score (continuous variable) with a sleep quality score (continuous variable) using Spearman's correlation. It had a significant p-value (p < 0.05).

And now, I would like to test some variables as confounding variables, like years of education (numeric), use of hypnotic and sedatives (dichotomous), suicide risk (dichotomous) and psychotherapeutic/farmacological treatment.

I use R to run all of my analysis. And my advisor said that I should consider confounding variables those associated with exposure and outcome with p-value < 0.20 in the crude analysis, considering a linear regression model.

What I've tried (that I actually don't know if it's correct or not and how should I interpret the output):

```
summary(lm(functioning_score ~ sleep_score + years_of_education + sleep_score*ages_of_education, data = data))
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = functioning_score ~ sleep_score + years_of_education + sleep_score*years_of_education, data = data)

Residuals:

   Min           1Q       Median           3Q          Max 

-29.08309673  -7.39316605  -1.09011226   5.49959525  31.53154265 

Coefficients:

   Estimate    Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)  
 
(Intercept)              7.9339474261  9.4999174669  0.83516 0.4073078 
  
sleep_score               2.1791574956  0.7761289987  2.80773 0.0069287

years_of_education            -0.3209011778  0.8309350862 -0.38619 0.7008713 
  
sleep_score:years_of_education -0.0144874634  0.0746344060 -0.19411 0.8468163   
---

Residual standard error: 11.106846 on 54 degrees of freedom

Multiple R-squared:  0.519259282,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.492551464
 
F-statistic: 19.4422205 on 3 and 54 DF,  p-value: 0.0000000112304043
```

Answer (score 4):

It is typically [not recommended](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10654-019-00494-6) to use p values as a criterion for the inclusion/non-inclusion of confounders. Ideally, if your sample size is adequate and the confounding variables are not highly predictive of your exposure (sleep score, in this instance), it is best to leave all identified confounders in the model. If you do have problems with sparse data and/or multicollinearity, see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4864881/) for some simple alternatives in this case.

With regard to the interpretation of the above linear model, I can see that you have only included one of the confounding variables - years of education. The included interaction term tests whether the association between sleep score and functioning varies with years of education.

Focusing on your exposure variable (interpreting results for confounders is [more complex](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/177/4/292/147738)). The results above show that a unit increase in sleep score is associated with a 2.18 unit increase in functioning score, when years of education is equal to zero. This is usually not very meaningful - few participants will have zero years of education. To make such results more sensical, it can be handy to center the years of education variable at its mean or another meaningful value (e.g. 12 years). This way, your exposure variable can be interpreted as, for example, 'a unit increase in sleep score is associated with a X unit increase in functioning score, when years of education is equal to 12 years'.

There is however, little evidence to indicate that the effect of score on functioning does depend on years of education (large p value for interaction term). So that interaction term may not need to be included. Keep in mind, however, that making data-driven adjustments to your model specification can lead to issues with your estimated standard errors and p values. So it is usually recommended to select a model a-priori, based on subject matter knowledge, and stick to that model as much as possible. The first hyperlink is an excellent guide to dealing with these questions - I highly recommend reading it.

Comment: @BrunoMontezano does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.